# Use stristr to match any value in array in a SINGLE if condition without multiple operators

Tags: php, arrays, string, if-statement

I'm pretty capable when coding PHP though I just came across a situation where I wondered if it would be possible to use `stristr` to match any value in an array inside a *SINGLE* if condition. I don't need/want a class, a dedicated function or anything super-complex nor am I doing anything complex such as trying to match special characters, I just think I may have missed something useful over at php.net.

The general notion...

```
if (stristr($search_this,$array_with_values)) {echo 'a match was found';}
```

...or what would amount to (even though this does not work)...

```
if (stristr($search_this,array('string1','string2'))) {echo 'a match was found';}
```

...I might try to find the strings 'apple','orange','banana' in a regular sentence/string.

I can define the array outside of the if condition.

My main goal is to simply not have numerous if conditions or use multiple operators such as && or ||.

So I do not want to have multiple || operators like this if possible...

```
if (
stristr($search_this_string,'string1') || 
stristr($search_this_string,'string2') || 
stristr($search_this_string,'string3')
) {echo 'a match was found';}
```

I don't mind having the array before/outside of the if condition though I want to be able to fit everything else inside of a single if condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt this is performant, but if you are looking for a reasonably simple-looking one-liner:

```
if( str_ireplace(array('string1', 'string2'), '', $str) != $str )
{
  echo 'a match was found';
}
```

Comment: I know str_ireplace is a fast function to use; tried this out and it works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

A regular expression would definitely be best for this one. Very short, and I 'd expect fastest than anything even remotely close to the length.

```
if(preg_match('/'.implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $needles)).'/i', $haystack)) {
    echo 'Match found!';
}
```

**Edit:** Regarding "stristr" being present on the question title... focus on the *problem*, not on a solution.

Comment: That would work and I voted up for your contribution however I avoid regular expressions in server-side code unless I absolutely need to use them as they tend to produce more load than other native functions. Regardless thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Might need to `array_map('preg_quote', $needles)`, depending on what characters are in the search strings.

Comment: @Phoenix: Very good suggestion, edited to incorporate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a workaround construct:

```
 if (array_filter(array_map("stristr", array_fill(0, count($array), $sentence), $array))) {
```

That will apply [`stristr`](http://php.net/stristr) to each element. [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) will keep only the set elements, so the boolean condition can either match (array with elements) or fail (empty array).

**Edit**: Ok, not that easy. You need an auxillary list (`array_fill` with source text) as using `stristr` requires two params from [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map).

Note that you give up short circuit evaluation with that. And despite common myths, it would be speedier to just use `preg_match` for such cases (might even be less code).

Comment: Voted up for creativity though going with a different solution, thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

This function would do what you want, if it is an acceptable approach:

```
function substr_in_array ($str, $array, $caseSensitive = FALSE) {
  if ($caseSensitive) {
    foreach ($array as $value) if (strpos($value, $str) !== FALSE) return TRUE;
  } else {
    foreach ($array as $value) if (stripos($value, $str) !== FALSE) return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}

if (substr_in_array($search_this, $array_with_values)) {
  echo 'a match was found';
}
```

As a side note, you seem to be using `strstr()` to detect *if* a substr exists, for which you should in fact be using `strpos()` (the same applies to `stristr()` and `stripos()`)

Comment: That works though I want to avoid adding custom functions if possible in PHP since it's native functionality is reasonably extensive, still voted up because that would work.