# Check if the string is contained in any listed arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, match

I'm executing a php program to return the files and folders in a given path. I need to exclude the files and folders that contain the string which are listed in the below arrays.

```
$folderArray = array("folder1", "temp");
$fileArray = array("test", "testing", "copy");
```

For example : I want to exclude folders with the word temp , files with the word copy (Eg: filename_copy.php) etc.

**Current code:**

```
$string = "filename-copy.php";   // this can be folder name/file name
foreach($folderArray as $a) {
    if (!stripos($string,$a) !== false) echo "yes";
    else echo "no";
}
foreach($fileArray as $a) {
    if (!stripos($string,$a) !== false) echo "yes";
    else echo "no";
}
```

But here I need to search in file array and folder array for the string in separate loops. Is there any other easy way to do this?

Can anyone help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468320/use-stristr-to-match-any-value-in-array-in-a-single-if-condition-without-multipl

Answer (score 1):

Here i am imploding these arrays `$folderArray` and `$fileArray` with `|` which in return make as pattern like this `folder1|temp`. So it will match any word either `folder1` or `temp`

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$folderArray = array("folder1", "temp");
$fileArray = array("test", "testing", "copy");


$string = "filename-copy.php";//sample filename
if(preg_match("/".  implode("|", $fileArray)."/", $string))
{
    echo "File to exclude";
}

$string = "foldername_temp";//sample folder name
if(preg_match("/".  implode("|", $folderArray)."/", $string))
{
    echo "folder to exclude";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP `in_array()` function to do a exact match

```
<?php
   $folderArray = array("folder1", "temp");
   $fileArray = array("test", "testing", "copy");
   if (in_array("filename-copy.php", $folderArray)) {
     echo "yes";
   }
?>
```

For the partial match you can use `strpos()`

```
function array_search_partial($arr, $keyword) {
    foreach($arr as $index => $string) {
        if (strpos($string, $keyword) !== FALSE)
            return $index;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would only match the full string though I believe? It wouldn't do a partial match on "copy".

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array of variable names and use `$$var_name` variable variables ([read more](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)).

```
<?php
$folderArray = array("folder1", "temp");
$fileArray = array("test", "testing", "copy");

$arrs = array('folderArray', 'fileArray');
$string = "filename-copy.php"; 

foreach ($arrs as $array_name) {
  foreach ($$array_name as $v) {
    if (!stripos($string, $v) !== false) {
      echo "yes";
    } else {
      echo "no";
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/772973

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combo of [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [`RecursiveFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php) (or [`RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator.php)). This way you will retrieve only needed files.

Take a look at [**the answer to the similar question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40740764/4355258). Particularly at this part:

```
$files = new CallbackFilterIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
            $path,
            FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
        ),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    ),
    $filter
);

foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    // Do something with files.
    var_dump($key, $file);
}
```

You can provide any filter function you want. In your case it will be something like this:

```
$folderArray = ["folder1", "temp"];
$fileArray = ["test", "testing", "copy"];

$filter = function ($current, $key, $iterator) use ($path, $folderArray, $fileArray) {
    $path = preg_quote($path, '/');
    $folderArray = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $folderArray));
    $fileArray = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $fileArray));

    if (
        preg_match('/^' . $path . '\/(' . $folderArray . ')/', $key)
        || preg_match('/' . $fileArray .  '/', $current->getFilename())    
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```